# How to guarantee the order of function calls in PHP?

Tags: php, multithreading, asynchronous

I want to implement a php service where 2 C# applications are involved, each application reads the output of its previous application and generates another output. I am wondering if this can be implemented just line by line, rather than requiring threads or some other asynchronous mechanism.

Users can upload a text file in [this webpage](http://www.matrixandcompany.com/), which leads to `uploadFile.php`, currently written as follows:

```
<?php
copy($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$n1 = "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
echo "Uploaded: " . $n1 . "<br>";
exec("mono c1.exe $n1");
echo "After running c1.exe";
$n2 ="uploads/c1_" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
exec("mono c2.exe $n2");
echo "After running c2.exe";
?>
```

Assume a user uploads `test.txt` in the webpage, `c1.exe` uses the content of `test.txt` and generates `c1_test.txt`, then `c2.exe` uses the content of `c1_test.txt` and generates `c2_test.txt`.

My tests (by just 1 user) show that the current `uploadFile.php` can perform this task step by step.

But I don't know if it is the right implementation for a web service that can be launched by many users.

Could anyone help?

**Edit 1:** If the order of execution can be respected, another concern is whether a user has to wait until all the tasks of his previous users have finished? In the case when `c1.exe` or `c2.exe` takes several minutes to run, this waiting without any feedback is annoying.

So does the current approach allows several users to run their tasks simultaneously (but in good order for each user)? Otherwise, do I have to implement a multi-threading by myself?

Comment: i see no issue with the approach above.

Comment: Let's assume `c1.exe` takes 5 minutes to run. What will happen if another user uploads a file just after a user? Is there a "queue" over there?

Comment: exec is blocking, unless you redirect the output

Comment: So when the server is busy, a user may have to wait long time to have its turn, without being informed... The only way to avoid this is multithreading?

Comment: Instead of writing the output to files that have to be cleaned up later, why not make the programs write to stdout and read from stdin? Simpler, a local instead of global solution (so you avoid the me for an unique ID) and possibly even more efficient.

Comment: I will still be able to keep the 2 C# applications separated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with [uniqueid](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.uniqid.php) :

```
<?php
$name = uniqid();
copy($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $name);
$n1 = "uploads/" . $name;
echo "Uploaded: " . $n1 . "<br>";
exec("mono c1.exe $n1");
echo "After running c1.exe";
$n2 ="uploads/c1_" . $name;
exec("mono c2.exe $n2");
echo "After running c2.exe";
?>
```

Comment: There is not queue, it's why we have to be sur that all files have different paths

Comment: So by default, the server manages well possibly simultaneous requests from different users?

Comment: no, you will have one process for each call to uploadFile.php which will be executed at the same time. But if the files have different name there will be no problem

Comment: This another example of PHP's stellar library. Apart from the naming, it's also a misnomer since it uses the current time to get a value. Rather trivial to make that one not unique obviously. Just use the process id or some sha256 hash of the input file instead.

Comment: @Voo Are you saying that this answer cannot guarantee a unique id? Could you please elaborate a little bit how to use process id or sha256?